# Disk Errors. FSCK returns 0

Tags: ssd, read-only, fsck

I've been having disk issues recently. The disk usually remounts as read only after 1 hour of uptime at which point the OS basically crashes. The disk is set to remount read-only after errors are encounter as per my fstab. i.e. `error=mount -ro`. I ran fsck yesterday while using a live USB and it returned 0 which apparently means no errors. Its an SSD (Crucial M4 120GB) so I'm wondering if it my be write fatigue.

Here's the dump from `dmesg`. Sorry about the pics, couldn't write to file as filesystem is RO at this point.

[image: Screen 1]

[image: Screen 2]

[image: Screen 3]

Comment: Interesting, I had that same issue with Ubuntu VM on Hyper-V and tracked it down to timeouts on an iSCSI connection. Could it be a either a crap cable or faulty disk controller?

Comment: @Mordoc The problem did start after I removed the drive from laptop to install a new OS on another drive. Its a laptop and when I was using the other drive I didn't screw it in, or even put it in the cage, I just plugged it in directly and replaced the cover. It was a pretty tight fit and I don't think I even moved the laptop after replacing the drive. I suppose there is a chance I could have bent the disk connector but seems unlikely.

Comment: You need to run `dmesg` and see what the error was that caused it to be remounted when this has happened.

Comment: @psusi I've added the `dmesg` dump.

Comment: It looks like the drive just crapped out.  Open the disk utility and go to the SMART tab and run the long self test.  This may take several hours.  Check the counts of offline_uncorrectable, pending, and reallocated sectors.

Answer (score 0):

What disk is it? I would recommend moving all the data off the disk, and doing `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/xxyy` where xxyy is the disk (**THIS WILL WIPE IT insecurely**). If it gives an error, replace the disk. Otherwise format it and move the data back on (I cannot provide any more support from here because I don't know what to do if it works.)